# Updating position for a list of markers

Tags: google-maps, gps, markers

I am working with Google Maps. Specifically, I am working with http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps for a gps tracker simulation, here I need to update the position on each point. 
At the gmaps script, markers are stored on an array, and then I was thinking of taking each point and using the setPoint method to update the position, however, the gmaps script doesn't have implemented this method. I was thinking on implement this method, but my question is then:
After having an array of markers on the gmaps script, how could I identify each one in order to update position on the correct marker.
Or probably I must store it on an external array, an associative array which help me to identifies each marker, but I am thinking that when I update them, the array on the gmap script also will be keeping at the same position without been updated.

I am attaching my code.

thanks

```
/** Positions and map statuses **/
var isLoaded = false;
/** **/
var refreshIntervalId;
var vehicles;
var map;
function setVehicleAsCenter (registration) {
    alert("Hola");
}
function loadPoints (positions) {
    console.debug('loading markers');
    var lttd;
    var lgtd;
    for (var i=0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        lttd = positions[i].latitude;
        lgtd = positions[i].longitude;
        marker = map.addMarker({
            lat: lttd,
            lng: lgtd,
        });
        markers[positions[i].registration] = marker;
    };
    map.fitZoom();
    isLoaded = true
}
function updatePoints (positions) {
    /**
    how could be the alorithm here
    */
    console.debug('updating markers');
}
function requestPoints() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'{% url 'gpstracking.ajax.request_tracks' %}',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            vehicles: vehicles
        },
        success: function (positions) {
            if (isLoaded == false) {
                loadPoints (positions);
            } else {
                updatePoints (positions);
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    /** Buttons Click Event Set **/
    $('.map-mode').click(function(){
        vehicles = '';
        $("#jstree").jstree("get_checked",null,true).find('a[rel="vehicle"]').each(function(){
            vehicles =  vehicles + $.trim(this.text) + "|";
        });
        if (vehicles == '') {
            console.debug('No vehicles to display');
            return;
        }
        option = $(this).attr('rel');
        if (option == 'show') {
            console.debug('Ordering to show');
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            requestPoints();
        }
        if (option == 'listen') {
            console.debug('Listening');
            requestPoints();
            refreshIntervalId = setInterval("requestPoints()", 10000);
        }
        if (option == 'clear') {
            console.debug('Clearing');
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            markers = new Object();
            map.removeMarkers();
            isLoaded = false;
        }
    });
    /** Map loading **/
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map-canvas',
        lat: -16.4237766667,
        lng: -71.54262,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMaps script is ok for simple maps, however on this case, I couldn't use it as I need, one option was refactored the script, but on this case I will use common gmaps loading with markers, and each marker I will set the id with my vehicle plates, in order  to each time, when I need to updated the position I look the marker for the id

```
function initializeMap() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-16.4237766667, -71.54262),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

function loadPoints (positions) {
        var lttd;
        var lgtd;
        var latlng;
        var iconMarker;
        var registration;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        $('#vehicle-status tbody').html('');
        for (var i=0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            index = positions[i].vehicle;
            lttd = positions[i].latitude;
            lgtd = positions[i].longitude;
            imei = positions[i].imei;
            registration = positions[i].vehicle;
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lttd, lgtd);
            imageIcon = getIconMarker(positions[i].course, positions[i].speed);
            var label = new Label({
                map: map
            });
            label.set('position', latlng);
            label.set('visible', true);
            label.set('text', registration);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                id: registration,
                map: map,
                position: latlng,
                icon: imageIcon,
                optimized: false,
                zIndex: i,
                label: label
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                loadContent(map, this, infowindow);      
            });
            markers[index] = marker;
            if (positions.length > 1) {
                bounds.extend(latlng);
            }
            $('#vehicle-status tbody').append(htmlStatusString(positions[i], true))
        };
        codeLatLng();
        if (positions.length == 1) {
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lttd, lgtd));
        } else {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        isLoaded = true
    }
```

Probably a harder way, however I have the whole control of the map, and I could use it as I need

Comment: Would you please expand upon this answer, with more details of the problem with your model definition, in case future readers face the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I will update also with some code an links were I have found the error, also I have mistake the answer related to other issue found, but I will paste it the right answer, and how I have solved